# Get notified/receive explicit intents when an activity starts

Tags: android

I am developing an application that gets notified when an `Activity` chosen by a user is started. For this to work, the best approach would be to register a `BroadcastReceiver` for `ACTION_MAIN` explicit `Intent`s, which as far as I know doesn't work (because these `Intent`s have specific targets). Another, probably less efficient approach, is to use the system `ActivityManager` and poll on the `getRunningTask()` which returns a list of all running tasks at the moment. The polling can be done by a background service. By monitoring the changes in this list, I can see whether an activity is running or not, so that my application can get notified. The downside is of course the polling. I have not tried this yet, but I think that this last approach will probably work.

Does anyone know of a better approach(es) or suggestions which are less intensive?

Comment: I have implemented the second possibility. It all depends on your app how often you want to poll

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just call `getParent()`?

This would be in your child `Activity`

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = new Intent();

    //Create this method in your Parent Activity
    getParent().onChildCreated(this, intent); 
}
```

This would be in your parent `Activity`

```
public void onChildCreated(Activity child, Intent intent) {
    /*
     * Have fun (Edited to pass intent)
     */
}
```